# “/bin/bash : - : Invalid option" with gitlab-CI and makefile with .ONESHELL

Tags: bash, makefile, gitlab-ci

I have a CI that works with gitlab-CI.

My (YAML gitlab-CI) pipeline script calls a makefile.

```
Build:
  stage: ThisIsAnExample
  script: 
    - export OPTION1=true; make -C build/ myTarget
```

In my makefile, i have the option .ONESHELL with the following options:

```
.ONESHELL:
SHELL = /bin/bash
.SHELLFLAGS = -ec -o pipefail

myTarget:
    @echo "A";echo ""; print "B\n";  echo "C";  echo "";
```

This works in local but fails in the CI with the error `/bin/bash: - : invalid option`

If I remove the `-o pipefail`, the error is fixed in the CI (but i have no more pipefail).

Any hints to make it work in the CI?

Notes:

- bash version for local console:
  `GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`
- bash version for ci server:
  `GNU bash, version 4.2.46(2)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)`

Comment: None of this requires `.ONESHELL`. The `-ec` looks really odd; probably take out the `c`?

Comment: Are you really sure your Makefile works in local? Or is it only the recipe when you enter it on the CLI?

Comment: I run the same commands in local that are written in the gitlab-ci script

Comment: @tripleee obviously it is not the genuine makefile script

Comment: I can see how it is reduced in form; but even if the commands are more complex, you don't need `.ONESHELL` if you merge them onto one logical line with `;` between them.

Comment: i don't need a bike, but i'd rather ride it than walk

Comment: btw it is not "reduced in form" but reduced in content. Much more complex and '; \' doesn't help reading

Comment: Could it be that it is not the shell spawned by make that fails but instead to one spawned by your CI runner? What if you replace the script by `export OPTION1=true; echo "OK"`?

Comment: I'm not convinced we're understanding the problem.  Try adding `-x` to `.SHELLFLAGS` and see what you get.  Also you should absolutely remove the `@`; that is the very first step anyone should take when debugging makefiles.  Adding `@` is like putting on a blindfold before taking target practice.  Then show us the full output, cut and pasted.  Also you can try adding `-d` to the make command line.

Comment: where's `bash -l` involved as mentioned in the title?

Comment: @pynexj ty for mentionning the typo in the title

Comment: `/bin/bash: - : invalid option` -- are you sure there's a SPACE between `-` and the 2nd `:`?